# Tree: free(): invalid pointer Aborted in C++

Tags: c++, tree, free

I got an error saying free (): invalid pointer Aborted after running the following code. (I have the correct output) The purpose of this piece of code is to construct from a pre-order tree and print the tree in post order.

```
struct node{
  int value;
  int child;
  int childspace;
  int parentspace;
  node *siblings;
};
```

The following is to construct tree from post order:

```
node *insertNode(node *t,int value,int child,int parent){
  if(t == NULL){
    t = new node();
    t->value=value;
    t->childspace=child;
    t->child=child;
    t->parentspace=parent;

    if(child==0){
      t->siblings = NULL;

    } else {
      t->siblings = new node[child];
      for(int i = 1;i <= t -> child; i++){
        cin >> value;
        cin >> child;
          t->siblings = insertNode(t->siblings, value, child, t->child);

          if(t->childspace >= 2){
          t->siblings += 1;
            t->childspace--;
          }
      }
    }
  } else {
    t->value=value;
    t->child=child;
    t->childspace=child;
    t->parentspace=parent;

    if(child == 0){
      t->siblings =NULL;

    } else {
      t->siblings =new node[child];

      for(int i=1; i<=t->child; i++){
        cin >> value;
        cin >> child;
          t->siblings = insertNode(t->siblings, value, child, t->child);

        if(t->childspace >= 2){
          t->siblings += 1;
            t->childspace--;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return t;
}
```

This function is to print tree from postorder:

```
void printTree(node* t){
  int mark=0;

  if(t == NULL){
    return;
  }

  if(mark==0){

    for(int i=0; i<t->child;i++){
      if(i == t->child - 1){
      }else {t->siblings--;}
    }
  }

  printTree(t->siblings);
  if(t->parentspace<=1){
    cout << t->value << " " << t->child << "\n";

  } else {
    mark=1;
    for(int i=0;i<t->parentspace; i++){
      if(i>0){
    if(t->child >1){
      for(int i=0;i<t->child; i++){
        if(i == t->child - 1){
            }else {t->siblings--;}
      }
    }
    printTree(t->siblings);
      }
      cout << t->value << " " << t->child<< "\n";
      if(i != t->parentspace-1) t++;

    }
  }
}

void free(node *t){
  if (t == NULL){
    return;
  } 
  if (t->child == 0){
    delete t;
    return;
  } else {

 for (int i = 0; i < t->child; i++){
    free(t->siblings);
    if (i!= t->child -1) t->siblings++;

  }
}
  delete t;

}
```

Here is an example:
input: (node, number of child)

```
3 2
2 0
1 0
```

output:

```
2 0
1 0
3 2
```

Error I got:
free (): invalid pointer Aborted

Edit:

I change free() to deleteNode, but still not working.

```
void deletenode(node *t){
 for (int i = 0; i < t->child; i++){
  if (t->child == 1){
    delete []t;
  } else {

    delete t->siblings;
    if (i!= t->child -1) t->siblings++;

  }
}
  delete []t;

}
```

Comment: Don't name your own functions the same as standard library ones (`free` in this case), unless they are in a unique namespace (and don't then do `using namespace ...;` of course).

Comment: `siblings` is allocated using `new []`. You have to deallocate with `delete []`, you can't deallocate one at a time as it appears you're doing here.

Comment: Consider using smart pointers and standard containers rather than manual memory management.